# How to maintain npm dependency versioning in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json, sinopia

I have a Node module published to private NPM repo like this

1. myModule@1.0.0.dev-43
2. myModule@1.0.0.rc-01

I want to have a `package.json` dependencies to download DEV module for local install but RC module for production builds.

Is there a way to achieve it in NPM?

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish the artifacts to your sinopia instance with a scope (ie: @local) and then register that scope with your local instance. Then when doing `npm install` all scoped dependencies will be sent to your local repo and everything else will go to the default repo.